# Download artifact from Nexus

Tags: api, maven, curl

I am trying to download a nexus/maven artifact using curl or wget, but I always get an "403 - Forbidden".

URL: http://nexus.domain.com:8081/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=snapshots&g=com.domain.org&c=dist-main&a=domain-server&v=LATEST&p=tar.gz

I tried using the following ip address, but it does not accept the credentials. The user exists, password is correct and have access to the repository. Does the user need special requirements?

```
curl -X GET -u user:password $URL
```

Or is there any way to use the api access key with curl? I am using Nexus 2.11.3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User account does not have the permission to do so. Talk to your Nexus admin.

Comment: Do you know which permissions are needed? I tried the admin account, but it does not work with that account either.

Comment: @bert2002, post curl verbose log and debug output from Nexus. Something must not be right with your setup.

Comment: I could figure it out. The role "Nexus Developer Role" was needed to have access to that. After adding this to the user it worked. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: What privs does the "Nexus Developer Role" have to be able to download?

Answer (score 13):

you need to include -O parameter to download

```
curl -X GET -u user:password $URL -O
```

If you don't want the password to show in your history. This will prompt for a password

```
curl -X GET -u user $URL -O
```